# How can I make in Kivy by clicking a button to change the text of another button(buttons)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm working on Kivy framework to create desktop app.

For example, when you click the "Eng" button, it changes the text of the button (s) to English. By analogy, when you click on button named "Fra", it changes to French.

[image: Example]

I've tried to costume the construction when your enter some information in Textinput and after clicking the Button information appears on Label. I'm just replaced Label with Button but I still don't know how to make it work.

My test.py file

```
class Container(BoxLayout):
    pass
    button_test=ObjectProperty()
    wbutton_eng=ObjectProperty()
    wbutton_fra=ObjectProperty()

    def change_text(self):
        self.buttontest.text
        self.wbutton_fra.text()
        self.wbutton_eng.text()
```

My KV file

```
<Container>:
    BoxLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 120, 1, 1, 0.9
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size

        orientation:'vertical'

        button_test:buttonone
        wbutton_eng:buttoneng
        wbutton_fra:buttonfra

        Button:
            id:buttonone
            text:'[color=ff3333]Text in French or English[/color]'
            font_size:24
            size_hint:1,0.09
            background_color: 0,0,0.5
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 2, 0.3, .6
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            markup: True

        Button:
            id:buttoneng
            text:'[color=ff3333]Eng[/color]'
            font_size:24
            size_hint:1,0.09
            background_color: 0,0,0.5
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 2, 0.3, .6
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            markup: True
                on_press
                    root.change_text()
        Button:
            id:buttonfra
            text:'[color=ff3333]Fra[/color]'
            font_size:24
            size_hint:1,0.09
            background_color: 0,0,0.5
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1, 2, 0.3, .6
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            markup: True
                on_press
                    root.change_text()
```

Comment: show what you tried from a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is to create a dictionary that contains as a key an identifier of the language and as a value the text to translate. Then associate each button with the language identifier.

A simple example is as follows:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class Container(BoxLayout):
    message = StringProperty()

    def retranslate(self, language):
        texts = {"en": "Hello World", "fr": "Salut monde"}
        self.message = texts.get(language, "")


Builder.load_string(
    """
<Container>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        text: root.message
    Button:
        text: "Eng"
        on_press: root.retranslate("en")
    Button:
        text: "Fra"
        on_press: root.retranslate("fr")
"""
)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        w = Container()
        w.retranslate("en")
        return w


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```